# Uncreated objects in generated api client using Swagger-API

Tags: c#, swagger, webapi

I like to use an created api client from a swagger hub.
I use the following swagger api:
`https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Comline/helic-portal-mandant-api-arze/1.11.0#/info`

I have downloaded the api in json from swagger hub. See the following screenshot.

[image]

After that, i create a "service reference" to my c# project (.NET 6)

[image]
[image]

I thought I can use this API client directly, but there was still a problem in the generated C# file.

There was an object with the name **UserDTO** which was not generated automatically.

```
/// <summary>Service für die Vorgangsanlage (Berichtigung)</summary>
/// <param name="processBerichtigungCreateRequestV5,UserDTO">Datenobjekt beinhaltet die Attribute für die Vorgangsanlage (Berichtigung)</param>
/// <returns>Aufruf des Service für die Vorgangsanlage wurde erfolgreich durchgeführt</returns>
/// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ProcessBerichtigungResponseV5> ProcessBerichtigungCreateV5Async(ProcessBerichtigungCreateRequestV5 processBerichtigungCreateRequestV5,UserDTO)
{
     return ProcessBerichtigungCreateV5Async(processBerichtigungCreateRequestV5,UserDTO, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Questions:

- Now I am not sure, is it normal that when generating the API for a C# API client via the swaggerhub.com in Visual Studio 2022 there can be objects that are not automatically generated?
- Did the creator of the API make a mistake when creating the API?
- Should I recreate this object every time I update the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did the creator of the API make a mistake when creating the API?

Yes, it seems so. The problem is that some parameter names in the [API definition](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Comline/helic-portal-mandant-api-arze/1.11.0) include a comma - which makes them invalid identifiers in programming languages. This is why the generated code is not quite correct.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: processBerichtigungCreateRequestV5,UserDTO
                                                 ^^^
```

To try and work around the issue, you can open the downloaded OpenAPI JSON file in a text editor and do a search/replace and replace `,UserDTO` with an empty string. Then try to import the updated file into Visual Studio again.